# I am not able to connect to download blockchain in logoscoin. It shows active connection, I am also attach debug logs below:

Tags: bitcoind, linux

```
2015-01-24 06:18:15 Logos version v0.8.6.4-ga5aedeb-beta (2015-01-22 22:29:38 -0800)
2015-01-24 06:18:15 Using OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2015-01-24 06:18:15 Default data directory /root/.logos
2015-01-24 06:18:15 Using data directory /root/.logos
2015-01-24 06:18:15 Using at most 125 connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2015-01-24 06:18:15 Using 2 threads for script verification
2015-01-24 06:18:15 init message: Verifying wallet
2015-01-24 06:18:15 dbenv.open LogDir=/root/.logos/database ErrorFile=/root/.logos/db.log
2015-01-24 06:18:16 Bound to [::]:11050
2015-01-24 06:18:16 Bound to 0.0.0.0:11050
2015-01-24 06:18:16 init message: Loading block index
2015-01-24 06:18:16 Opening LevelDB in /root/.logos/blocks/index
2015-01-24 06:18:16 Opened LevelDB successfully
2015-01-24 06:18:16 Opening LevelDB in /root/.logos/chainstate
2015-01-24 06:18:16 Opened LevelDB successfully
2015-01-24 06:18:16 LoadBlockIndexDB(): last block file = 0
2015-01-24 06:18:16 LoadBlockIndexDB(): last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=1, size=266, heights=0...0, time=2014-05-20...2014-05-20)
2015-01-24 06:18:16 LoadBlockIndexDB(): transaction index disabled
2015-01-24 06:18:16 LoadBlockIndexDB(): hashBestChain=2d352b606e859728ff5a58bc8f6c980c44535c2707022e959aab4109aac1af2c  height=0 date=2014-05-20 14:00:00
2015-01-24 06:18:16 init message: Verifying blocks
2015-01-24 06:18:16  block index             101ms
2015-01-24 06:18:16 init message: Loading anonymous desktop wallet
2015-01-24 06:18:16 nFileVersion = 80604
2015-01-24 06:18:16  wallet                  185ms
2015-01-24 06:18:16 init message: Loading addresses
2015-01-24 06:18:16 Loaded 1 addresses from peers.dat  29ms
2015-01-24 06:18:16 mapBlockIndex.size() = 1
2015-01-24 06:18:16 nBestHeight = 0
2015-01-24 06:18:16 setKeyPool.size() = 100
2015-01-24 06:18:16 mapWallet.size() = 0
2015-01-24 06:18:16 mapAddressBook.size() = 1
2015-01-24 06:18:16 msghand thread start
2015-01-24 06:18:16 opencon thread start
2015-01-24 06:18:16 addcon thread start
2015-01-24 06:18:16 net thread start
2015-01-24 06:18:16 upnp thread start
2015-01-24 06:18:16 dnsseed thread start
2015-01-24 06:18:16 Loading addresses from DNS seeds (could take a while)
2015-01-24 06:18:16 dumpaddr thread start
2015-01-24 06:18:16 init message: Loading complete
2015-01-24 06:18:16 4 addresses found from DNS seeds
2015-01-24 06:18:16 dnsseed thread exit
2015-01-24 06:18:16 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:17 refreshWallet
2015-01-24 06:18:17 GetMyExternalIP() received [183.87.126.235] 183.87.126.235:0
2015-01-24 06:18:17 GetMyExternalIP() returned 183.87.126.235
2015-01-24 06:18:17 AddLocal(183.87.126.235:11050,4)
2015-01-24 06:18:18 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:18 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:20 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:20 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:21 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:22 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:23 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:24 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:24 No valid UPnP IGDs found
2015-01-24 06:18:24 upnp thread exit
2015-01-24 06:18:25 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:26 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:27 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:27 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:29 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:29 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:30 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:31 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:32 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:33 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:34 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:35 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:36 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:36 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:38 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:38 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:39 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:40 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:41 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:42 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:43 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:44 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:45 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:45 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:47 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:47 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:48 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:49 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:50 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:51 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:52 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:53 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:54 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:54 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:56 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:56 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:58 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:18:58 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:18:59 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:19:00 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:19:01 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:19:02 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:19:03 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:19:03 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:19:05 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:19:05 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:19:07 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:19:07 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:19:08 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
2015-01-24 06:19:09 trying connection 72.52.4.91:11050 lastseen=100.8hrs
2015-01-24 06:19:10 connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
```

when I tried to run bitcoin GUI it connected and show network and start download blockchain, this will not work. what I can do? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the seed node 72.52.4.91:11050 is down. You either need to provide additional seeds (by modifying your logoscoin.conf and using addnode) - or contact the coin developers and ask them to fix it.